# FTP to FTPS proxy

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ftps

Visual Studio 2010 allows to publish web projects via FTP. Great feature but due to security reasons FTP is disabled at the target site (FTPS is available). As far as I know VS2010 does not support FTPS ;(
Is there any plugin for VS2010 that implements FTPS support?
Or, maybe, a simple proxy for installation on the local PC that translate FTP to FTPS ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

VS 2010 supports publishing via FTPS (FTP/SSL).

Just use "ftps://yoursite.com" instead of "yoursite.com" in `Target Location` field.

For details see [VS 2010 Web Deployment blogpost](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/29/vs-2010-web-deployment.aspx)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.tlswrap.com/) tool can act as a ftps proxy, you connect to it via ftp and it connects to a remote ftps on your behalf.

http://www.tlswrap.com/